# Angular 2 Extending an NPM component Ngx-Modal with Wrapper

Tags: angular, inheritance, wrapper, ngx-modal

I am try to extend an existing working component locally in Angular 2.  I don't get any really useful indication of what the problem is, no errors etc.

So I modified an existing plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/8x34JbEhYdVms4iYLRvM?p=preview) that has an example of ngx-modal working.

*(I'm trying to get this technique right so it doesn't matter that it's ngx-modal, it just so happens to be one I found a good plunker on.)*

> I added an new component that extends the other...
>   **ngx-modal.component.ts**

```
//Extend and wrap NGX MODAL
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalModule } from "ngx-modal";

@Component({
    selector: 'ext-ngx-modal', 
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class NgxModalComponent extends ModalModule {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

> I wrapped the existing modal with 
>   **app.ts**

```
<ext-ngx-modal>
   <modal #myModal>
        <modal-header>
             <h1>Modal header</h1>
        </modal-header>
        <modal-content>
             Hello Modal!
        </modal-content>
        <modal-footer>
           <button class="btn btn-primary"(click)="myModal.close()">close</button>
       </modal-footer>
    </modal>
```

> and registered the component:

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {ModalModule} from "ngx-modal";
import {NgxModalComponent} from "ngx-modal.component"

@Component({
```

etc...

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,ModalModule ],
  declarations: [ App, NgxModalComponent ],
  exports: [ NgxModalComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

> **After this the plunker wont run...!**

[My extended Plunker-not working](https://plnkr.co/edit/xMm9LikyqtQe9gKfvk1U?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Modal / ModalModule

Your `NgxModalComponent` should import and extent `Modal`, not `ModalModule`:

```
export class NgxModalComponent extends Modal {
```

#### 2. Template syntax error

You forgot to close the `<ext-ngx-modal>` tag in your `App template`, should be:
`</ext-ngx-modal>`

#### 3. Plunker

I don't know how to properly reference files on imports in plunker, so I moved your components into a single file...

Here is a working [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/FK4Qc6zp1PB1yTh0ULkc?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, I had cut + pasted the ModalModule and needed to use the "Modal".  Nice one I'd gone code blind!

Comment: For a bonus point can anyone workout why the property isOpened is not changing in the example here...https://plnkr.co/edit/rTJsMq7XHg4zLmIjUARD?p=preview

Comment: @PaulThomas probably because you are opening an instance of `modal` (`(click)="myModal.open()"`), not `ext-ngx-modal`. So your `ext-ngx-modal` is indeed nere opened (and will always say `false`).

Comment: Yeah when I put the handler on my ext-modal it throws errors. 
 I've created a separate case for for that now. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704437/ngx-modal-when-extended-nativeelement-of-undefined-angular-2