# Ngx-Modal when extended 'NativeElement of undefined' Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, ngx-modal

This plunker should open up a modal when the button is pressed.  I have extended the existing ngx-modal but it throws error: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined.

> Having looked at the console this is because "modalRoot" should be programatically assigned as a ViewChild handler for the modal.  It doesn't seem to get defined when extended even though I've added the super() to my constructor, any ideas?

[Plunker that shows issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/FdbEFGObJnq4tFDsh2W2?p=preview)

```
    //our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, HostListener, ElementRef} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {ModalModule} from "ngx-modal";
import { Modal } from "ngx-modal";

@Component({
    selector: 'ext-ngx-modal', 
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class NgxModalComponent extends Modal {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    openExt():void {
      this.open();
    }

    @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
    onkeydown(ev: KeyboardEvent) {
        console.log("this.isOpened: " + this.isOpened;
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}} I am </h2>
      <div class="row container-fluid">
        <button (click)="myExtNgxModal.openExt()"> open my modal</button>
        <ext-ngx-modal #myExtNgxModal>
          <modal>
              <modal-header>
                  <h1>Modal header</h1>
              </modal-header>
              <modal-content>
                  Press F12 see the console...press a key while modal open
              </modal-content>
              <modal-footer>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="myModal.close()">close</button>
              </modal-footer>
          </modal>
        </ext-ngx-modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, ModalModule ],
  declarations: [ App, NgxModalComponent ],
  exports: [ NgxModalComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achive by extending modal class ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/mzSL6P2AtS4aF1azjo72?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui I linked to your plunker in my answer below. I hope that is OK. I've added much more information around it too, but don't want to steel any credit from you..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44715840/2521893

Comment: That's ok. I'm glad that you managed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Extending only the class - different templates

When your `NgxModalComponent` component extends the `Modal` component, it will inherit the code like you would imaging.

The problem is that you are overriding it's template with your own. This is a problem since some of the code you have inherited relies on the template of the original `Modal` component.

Here is an example from [the source code](https://github.com/pleerock/ngx-modal/blob/master/src/Modal.ts#L111) where the `Modal` is gaining access to an element in the template:

```
/***** FROM NGX-MODAL SOURCE *****/
@ViewChild("modalRoot")
public modalRoot: ElementRef;
```

When it invokes `open()`, [it's using this reference internally](https://github.com/pleerock/ngx-modal/blob/master/src/Modal.ts#L145) to set `focus` on its *native element*:

```
/***** FROM NGX-MODAL SOURCE *****/
window.setTimeout(() => this.modalRoot.nativeElement.focus(), 0);
```

Since you don't have a the same `template` and no element named *modalRoot*, it will fail.

#### Solution(s)

**Using `ContentChild`** ([docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild))

One solution is to use `ContentChild` to get a reference to the `Modal` that is wrapped inside you template. **yurzui** posted a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mzSL6P2AtS4aF1azjo72?p=preview) showing this in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704437/ngx-modal-when-extended-nativeelement-of-undefined-angular-2#comment76398697_44704437) (**yurzui** created this plunker, no credit to me for that!).

What he is doing is getting the modal reference and calling the `open()` method on the embedded `Modal` instance instead.

```
@ContentChild(Modal) modal: Modal;

  openExt():void {
    this.modal.open();
  }
```

**Rethinking your approach**

Another option is to rethink if your approach of extending this modal is really needed and the correct way forward. But that is up to you :)

I hope this helps!

Comment: perfect thanks Fredrik!  There's an issue with ARIA focus tabbing outside the modal so needed to do this.